# Почему происходит выполнение fmt.Println?

Tags: golang

Всем привет! Объясните пожалуйста, почему после записи данных в канал функция продолжает своё выполнение, и мы видим в консоли "hello" ? Ведь чтение и запись в канал порождают блокировку, в следствии чего начинает выполнятся другая горутина, то есть горутина main.
Однако, если вставить между записью в канал и выводом в консоль какой-то синхронный код (например, цикл с итерациями на ~250к), то при выполнении программы не во всех случаях будет выполняться вывод в консоль

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
)

func test (ch chan int) {
  ch <- 1

  fmt.Println("hello")
}

func main () {
  ch := make(chan int)

  go test(ch)
  <- ch
}
```

Comment: вывод в консоль выполняется быстрее, чем успевает завершится main

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном примере порядок и скорость выполнения не гарантированы. В Вашем случае первым завершается мини-функция, чем main, поэтому в консоль попадает вывод.

давайте запустим трассировку выполнения программы и посмотрим какая функция как выполнялась.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "runtime"
    "runtime/trace"
)

func test(ch chan int) {
    ch <- 1

    fmt.Println("hello")
}

func main() {
    err := trace.Start(os.Stderr)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    ch := make(chan int)

    go test(ch)
    <-ch
    runtime.StopTrace()
}
```

```
$ go run main.go 2> trace.out
$ go tool trace trace.out  
2021/08/02 14:11:29 Parsing trace...
2021/08/02 14:11:29 Splitting trace...
2021/08/02 14:11:29 Opening browser. Trace viewer is listening on http://127.0.0.1:62212
```

откроется браузер со страницей результатов трассировки. нужно выбрать "View trace"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]